# Store random number and score

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, random

I just started programming for few days.
I want to ask the user different questions and if they type in the right question then I will give them a score of 5 marks for getting the question right, plus bonus marks which are given by using Random, this bonus(Random) is then added to the total score(score(5) + random) which is stored and used to add the next score of the following question and the process repeats with all the questions[5].
This is what I have done so far, but it keeps printing the same result for every question and I want to keep adding to the previous score.

```
        for (int attempts = 1; attempts <= 3; attempts++);
    {   
        Random dice = new Random(); 
        for(int n = 0; n <QArray.length; n++)
        {

        System.out.println("Question" + (n+1));
        System.out.println(QArray[n]);

            for(int m =0; m<3; m++)
            {
            String ans = scanner.nextLine();    

            int t = dice.nextInt(9) + 1;
            int scoremarks = 5;  
              if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(AArray[n]))
              {
              System.out.println("That is correct!\nYour score is:" + scoremarks + "\nWith virtual dice your total score is:" + (scoremarks +t));

              break;
              }
              else 
              {
              System.out.println("That is incorrect!\nYou got 0 Marks\nYour score is 0!");
              }
```

Comment: You should just keep reusing your dice, instead of creating a new one every iteration.

Comment: Move the `Random dice = new Random();` out of both loops. i.e. before the outer loop.

Comment: I moved the Random dice = new Random(); out of both loops. But still the output for getting right questions is i.e: "First Question" You go it right.... score:5 , total score:10... "second question" you got it right... score: 5, total score:8..... But I want to add to the total score from the 1st question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain the score outside the loop. You can print totalScore after all the questions and will have the total score of all the right answers.

```
    int totalScore = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < QArray.length; n++) {
        System.out.println("Question" + (n + 1));
        System.out.println(QArray[n]);

        for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
            String ans = scanner.nextLine();
            Random dice = new Random();
            int t = dice.nextInt(9) + 1;
            int scoremarks = 5;
            if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(AArray[n])) {
                totalScore += (scoremarks + t);
                System.out.println("That is correct!\nYour score is:" + scoremarks + "\nWith bonus your total score is:" + (scoremarks + t));
                // correct = false;
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("That is incorrect!\nYou got 0 Marks\nYour score is 0!");
            }
        }
    }
```

With a few optimizations as mentioned in the comments:

```
    int totalScore = 0;
    Random dice = new Random();
    int scoremarks = 5;
    for (int n = 0; n < QArray.length; n++) {
        System.out.println("Question" + (n + 1));
        System.out.println(QArray[n]);

        for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
            String ans = scanner.nextLine();
            int t = dice.nextInt(9) + 1;
            if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(AArray[n])) {
                totalScore += (scoremarks + t);
                System.out.println("That is correct!\nYour score is:" + scoremarks + "\nWith bonus your total score is:" + (scoremarks + t));
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("That is incorrect!\nYou got 0 Marks\nYour score is 0!");
            }
        }
    }
```

You can print totalScore in the condition when the answer is correct to see score increase each time the answer is correct. Also for the case when the answer is not correct, you can still show the total score to see how many points you might have from the previous questions. Not sure if there are 3 tries for getting the answer right but that's what the inside for loop seems to be doing so the message for incorrect guess seems inappropriate.